# Stream from TCPClient catching data from next packet

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I'm developing some software that listens for events from another program via TCP.

The events come in a string formatted like this: "value1;value2;value3"
The problem is that sometimes a single character from value1 gets read onto the previous event so i get something like this:

value1;value2;value3v

alue1;value2;value3

How can i make it know where each message begins and ends?

Here is the code:

```
Dim client As New TcpClient()

Sub listen()
    Dim networkStream As Stream = client.GetStream()
    While True

        Dim bytes(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        Dim size As Integer = 0
        size = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(client.ReceiveBufferSize))

        'process event here

    End While
End Sub
```

This is all done on a thread of it's own.

Comment: CInt(client.ReceiveBufferSize) -1: you mean like that?

Comment: anyways, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sender has to included the length of each data its sending so at receiver you will receive upto the provided length. Easier option would be to include NULL termination so that you can read it as individual string at receiver end.