# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array vb.net infinite loop

Tags: vb.net

I’m performing an infinite loop and I have a problem with this block of code:

```
Dim infiniteCounter As Integer

For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
    infiniteCounter = 1

    Try
        Dim dataFromClient As String
        Dim bytesFrom(50024) As Byte
        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
```

The specific line that raises a problem is:

```
Dim bytesFrom(50024) As Byte
```

This error is raised:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: How do you know an exception is thrown if you're swallowing all exceptions in an empty catch block? Why is the code written this way? What's the purpose of `infiniteCounter`? Why don't you start at 0, instead of 1?

Comment: maybe it's just me, but this question looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868913/stream-from-tcpclient-catching-data-from-next-packet

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see if there is data in bytesFrom before trying to access it:

```
If bytesFrom IsNot Nothing AndAlso bytesFrom.Length > 0 Then
    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
End If
```

Additionally you should wrap any specific line that could have an exception in a try/catch rather than a whole block of code (e.g. getting the stream, reading it into a variable, and decoding the byte array).